# React Router not found page showing up on all paths

Tags: reactjs

I'm experimenting with a bit of React Routing, and I experienced a problem when I tried to make an error page, which occurs each time the users gets a 404 error, which prompts a message:

```
import React from "react";

const Error = props => {
    return(
        <div>
        <p>
            Path does not exist!
        </p>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Error;
```

I wrapped all my paths, with a switch statement, to only make it apply to the absolute paths.

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/"   component={Home}  />
      <Route exact path="/about"  component={About} />
      <Route path="*" exact component={Error} />
      </div>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

but know whenever I access a path, the Error component shows up.

But I since I wrap in a Switch component, and use exact, shouldn't the Error component only show up, whenever another path does not exist?

Comment: shot in the dark but have you tried removing the `div`? Also the `path="*"` is not needed you do not have to supply the path param if you always want it to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"   component={Home}  />
      <Route exact path="/about"  component={About} />
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
```

Do not add a path for error route.